# Prove or disprove: $(\frac{1}{n})^n(1 - \frac{1}{n})^{n^2-n} \simeq \frac{1}{n!}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: asymptotics, factorial

Prove or disprove:  $(\frac{1}{n})^n(1 - \frac{1}{n})^{n^2-n} \simeq \frac{1}{n!}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I'm trying to prove the statement by building on my observation that $(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$ tends to $\frac{1}{e}$, which appears in Stirling's approximation for $n!$.

Comment: What does the Stirling formula tells you, if you replace $1/e$ by $(1-1/n)^n$?

Comment: @digital-Ink It tells nothing. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{n^n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2-n} \sim \frac{1}{n!}
\iff
\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}
\sim \frac{n^n}{n!}
\iff \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}
\sim \frac {e^{n-1}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}
\\
 %\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}
%=\exp \left[ n^2\log \left(1-\frac 1n
%\right)
%\right]
%=\exp \left[ n^2 \left(-\frac 1n
%-\frac 1{n^2} + O\left( \frac{1}{n^3}\right)
%\right)\right]
%= e^{-1-n}+o(1)
$$

LHS goes to $0$ and RHS to infinity.